# Apache NiFi : Validate the FlowFile data created by ConsumeKafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am pretty new to NiFi. We have the setup done already where we are able to consume the Kafka messages. 
In the NiFi UI, I created the Processor with ConsumeKafka_0_10. When the messages are published (different process), My processor is able to pick up the required data/messages properly.
I go to "Data provenance" and can see that the correct data is received.

However, I want to have the next process as some validator. That will read the flowfile from consumekafka and do basic validation (user-supplied script should be good)

How do we that or which processor works here?

Also any way to convert the flowfile input format into csv or json format?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. Depending on the flowfile content format, you can use `ValidateRecord` with a `*Reader` record reader controller service configured to validate it. If you already have a script to do this in Groovy/Javascript/Ruby/Python, `ExecuteScript` is also a solution.

Similarly, to convert the flowfile content into CSV or JSON, use a `ConvertRecord` processor, with a `ScriptedReader` and a `CSVRecordSetWriter` or `JsonRecordSetWriter` to output into the correct format. These processes use the Apache NiFi record structure internally to convert from arbitrary input/output formats with high performance. Further reading is available at [blogs.apache.org/nifi](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) and [bryanbende.com](https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/06/20/apache-nifi-records-and-schema-registries).

Comment: Thanks, I will try these....looks like one of these options should solve my issue. Thanks again..

Comment: Thanks Andy for the above. It helped me to solve my problem. Some details:
1. I used the ExecuteScript processor after my ConsumeKafka processor.
2. I used custom groovy script to read the flowfile contents and operate on it as per the business rules.
3. The output of ExecuteScript was given to Routeattribute processor, since I had to route it, as per the logic, to different processor.

Thanks again.